# Basic callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to better understand "[continuation-passing style](http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/continuation-passing-style.html)"

Converting synchronous code

```
  function loadAvatarImage(id) {
        var profile = loadProfile(id);
        return loadImage(profile.avatarUrl);
    }
```

To async

```
   function loadAvatarImage(id, callback) {
        loadProfile(id, function (profile) {
            loadImage(profile.avatarUrl, callback);
        });
    }
```

How is it that `loadProfile` passes in `profile` in the second argument, how does it know to wait for `loadProfile` to resolve before calling `loadImage(profile.avatarUrl, callback)`?

Comment: That does depend on the implementation of `loadProfile`, which you haven't shown. Notice the name refers to different functions in the different examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article implies that every function should be asynchronous.
Therefore, the `loadProfile` function takes a `callback` as well

```
function loadProfile(id, callback) { ... }
```

Now "that" function should do it asynchronously and when it is done, then call the callback function.
Typically loading data in AJAX, or else.

From the first few paragraphs, it seems that the author is not doing anything actually asynchronous. It is just recursive functions with callbacks. But it all happens synchronously unless you have an asynchronous (or deferred) call somewhere which is not the case of the first examples given.

Another approach to asynch programming in javascript is via a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it that loadProfile passes in profile in the second argument, how does it know to wait for loadProfile to resolve before calling loadImage(profile.avatarUrl, callback)?

Something along these lines:

```
function loadProfile( id, callback ) {

    var picture = '¯\_(ツ)_/¯';

    // setTimeout to simulate any other async process, like fetching an image
    setTimeout( function ( ) {
        // Calls callback after 1 second
        callback( picture );
    }, 1000 );
}
```